# Are there any santizing ModelBinders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I'm curious if anyone is using a ModelBinder that sanitizes input at binding time. This seems like it would be a useful feature, but I haven't seen much discussion on the topic. Does anyone have any input?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't sanitize at input type (except of course validation). I sanitize at output time. For example the [AntiXss](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library could be used when you need to output some HTML on a view that you obtained from an untrusted source (such as a user of your site). But if the application doesn't need to accept HTML from users and show this HTML without encoding, the standard `Html.DisplayFor` helper (or the corresponding tag `<%:` for WebForms or `@` for Razor) does the job in most cases.